# Using unordered_map with dyanmically-allocated user-defined class

Tags: c++, pointers, unordered-map, user-defined-types

So I've got a class, "Room", which has the following code:

```
class Room
{
public:
    Room(string name, string desc): name(name), desc(desc) {}
    void operator=(const Room room)
    {
        name = room.name;
        desc = room.desc;
    }
    string getName(); //returns this.name
    string getDesc(); //returns this.desc

private:
    string name; //name of the room
    string desc; //description of the room
};
```

I've got a global variable in my main.cpp of type unordered_map, like this:

```
unordered_map<string, *Room> rooms; //Room's name is the key
```

And I want to allocate Rooms on the fly in a function and add them to my map. I attempted to do it like this:

```
void builder()
{
    Room* room = new Room("Name", "Desc");
    rooms[room->getName()] = room;
}
```

...But I'm getting all kinds of compiler warnings. I figured it would be something to do with iterators or hashing, or I'm not using pointers correctly (which are probably all true), but mostly it seems unordered_map doesn't like being parametrized with Room or *Room. Am I missing something?

Comment: Compiler warning are hints to the problem.  It would make sense to add at least some of them to the question so people can quickly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax errors as `*Room`. I have some tips

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Room
{
public:

    Room(string name, string desc)
      : name(name) // This syntax is called initializer list 
      , desc(desc)
    {

    }

    void operator = (const Room room)
    {
        name = room.name;
        desc = room.desc;
    }

    string getName() { return name; }
    string getDesc() { return desc; }

private:
    string name; //name of the room
    string desc; //description of the room
};

// Without using unique_ptr you have a memory leak
// because the is not explicitly called the delete operator on pointers
unordered_map<string, std::unique_ptr<Room> > rooms;

void builder()
{ 
  Room* room = new Room("Name", "Desc");
  rooms[room->getName()].reset (room);
}
```

Comment: Ah, unique_ptr seems to solve some of my memory management problems! It also fixed my underlying syntax issue, which I hadn't suspected. Thank you.